# SSH: connection reset after idle for some time

Tags: centos, ssh, sshd, cygwin, timeout

When my connection has been idle for some time, the remote host closes the connection. I try to type a new command, it hangs, then closes the connection. How can I keep the ssh connection active for longer?

```
$ ssh root@host.com
Last login: Tue Jan  3 03:09:39 2017 from c-99-99-99-99.hsd1.xx.comcast.net
[root@ip-172-99-99-99 ~]# groups
root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel
[root@ip-172-99-99-99 ~]# users
root root
[root@ip-172-99-99-99 ~]# less /etc/passwd
[root@ip-172-99-99-99 ~]# Connection reset by 52.99.99.99 port 22
```

The remote is CentOS on Amazon (AWS) and local is Cygwin.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because your last login was from comcast.net I am guessing that you are connecting from a `home` system where you are behind a router which is doing NAT. A problem that a system doing NAT has is knowing when the connection is no longer wanted. If the connection is taken down cleanly then there is no problem but if the two machines just reboot then there is no signal to the NAT box that this has happened. Therefore your typical NAT box has timers which say "if there is no traffic for an hour then the two endpoints clearly are not going to send anything more" and so recycles the resources that the NAT was taking.

So the thing to do is send some traffic every once in a while. The simplest way assuming you are using the `openssh` implementation on your cygwin machine is to enable TCPKeepAlive. replace

```
ssh root@host.com
```

with

```
ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=true root@host.com
```

For long term use you are better setting up a `~/.ssh/config` file.

```
 host fred
     hostname host.com
     user root
     TCPKeepAlive=true
```

and then you will be able to say just `ssh fred` to connect to the machine with the needed option.

Comment: Excellent description and inference! `debug1: /home/Chloe/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for host.com`

Comment: Sometimes the connection is reset even when it hasn't been idle. It says it was reset by the IP address of the remote host, but when I log back in, the machine hasn't been restarted. I'm the only user.

Comment: The thing I was suggesting was resetting the connect was the box doing NAT, i.e. your cable modem. However because of the way that TCP/IP works it is just possible that you are seeing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_reset_attack

Answer (score -1):

It is using your last saved session SSH keys.

You will have to delete it and then `ssh` will add new keys for the IP address you are trying to access.

```
ssh-keygen -f "/home/asagarwal-dev/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 10.0.0.6
```

The above command solved my problem (where `10.0.0.6` is the IP address which I was trying to `ssh` from host).

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question.

Answer (score -4):

As ssh client configure it below here :

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

`sudo source ~/.ssh/config`

All remote host configure it below here :

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Comment: What the heck should `sudo source ~/.ssh/config` do?

Comment: Just create config file in ssh client with host * and ServerAliveInterval 60

Comment: @Jakuje,joking with 9853 reputation.Did you earn your reputation from corruption? Voted my answer minus.

Comment: I followed my linux/Unix forum.I didnt follow linux/Unix forum like this forum.Showing their arrogancy to many user here.I dont mind to give my all reputation to you.Dont need to vote my answer minus.

Comment: Deleted my answer when my answer was wrong.Deleted my question when my question was wrong.

Comment: Hello. This is not a forum, but Q&A. Good answers go up and bad down. I am pointing out what is wrong in your answer (by simple question) and letting you fix it if you dare. Good answers also explain why is the problem happening, not just pasting snippets of configuration files and commands without explanation.

Comment: This answer got it from linux tutorial website.Can I transfer 10 reputations to you?If you want it.Who asked this question? You or others? Why did you make noise? Some answers are wrong in this site.Why you didnt vote it minus? Many answers are joking here.Some of them are your friends. They didnt vote minus.I didnt do bookmark on the link.So I saved it as pdf using UC browser on android.I sent it to you.The article title "Preventing ssh connection disconnecting"

Comment: I am not stupid.Because I always checked an answer from internet.I knew the answer was correct or wrong.