# Is there any way of stopping an SSH connection from having timeouts?

Tags: ssh, sshd, cloud

When I use a Linux server on my house and I access it from the Internet, I can keep the terminal window open with an SSH connection for as long as I want. However, when I use a Linux server on cloud services like AWS or Oracle cloud, my terminal always freezes after some minutes I leave it idle. That bothers me a lot because many times I'm still researching about the subject that I'm doing and then my SSH connection with the cloud is frozen when I come back. That results in me having to close the terminal and reopen the connection with a new one, and then reopening everything again, so I end up spending a lot of time on this during the day. I've looked in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` if I could find anything related to connection timeouts to understand why it happens but I didn't find anything.

Also, I've found [this question here on Unix Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334440/444310) that seems related. According to the accepted answer, if I use the parameter `-o TCPKeepAlive=true` while connecting with `ssh` this problem would be solved. In my case, it didn't solve the problem at all, the connection still freezes after some time idle, the command that I used was something like the following:

```
ssh -i myprivatekey -o TCPKeepAlive=true user@serverip
```

Is there any configuration I can change on my computer or the server to solve this problem? How can I make an SSH connection stop freezing after being idle for a while?

Comment: You have to find out first it if is an actual `ssh` timeout or, for example, a firewall somewhere along the way sending an RST after some time (could it be upstream or downstream). Leave a process with constant output, something like `while sleep 5; do date; done'. Does it stop too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing `-o ServerAliveInterval=20` which would regularly send some poking data as part of the ssh protocol and may help with your issue.

Also you may want to use the `tmux` or `screen` terminal multiplexers in your `ssh` session, so it would just be a matter of reattaching your session when you reconnect instead of having to *restart everything*.

Comment: I've tested passing `-o ServerAliveInterval=20` to connect on an Oracle cloud server but it still freezes after some time ;/... But thanks for the `tmux` and `screen` suggestions, I already use them for background processes sometimes but I didn't think of using them in this case...

Comment: @raylight, try running `ssh` is a few `-v` options (or enter `~v` a few times from within your ssh session) to see if that can give you any clue.